# JSON POST without XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

I have the following code that work perfectly on my own site, however I want to execute it on zapier which doesn't seem to support the XMLHttpRequest and im not sure how to change the code to accommodate. I am a bit new to working with json so any help is appreciated.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "www.url.com", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(
        {
          "values": {
            "1": "Test Name",
            "2": "123"
          }
        }
    ));
```

update:
ok, so I tried:

```
 fetch("www.url.com",
 {
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          "values": {
            "1": "name",
            "13": "123"
          }
        }
    )
 })
```

and got the error "If you are doing async (with fetch library) you need to use a callback!" So I think the code is working, there is just other things to figure out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` (and `fetch` which is subject to most of the same limitations as `XMLHttpRequest`, but with limited browser support) is the only way to make an HTTP request with a JSON formatted body from JavaScript running in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out the Zapier documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-http-example) for creating HTTP requests. Looks like you are missing the `.catch(callback);` portion.